# how to position tooltip over where mouse is?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My tooltip is stuck in one place no matter which link I hover over and I dont know whats wrong. Is there a way I can adjust this code so that the tooltip appears over the link I hover over?

```
.tooltip {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}

.tooltip-content {
    position: absolute;
    background: url(../img/shape1.svg) no-repeat center bottom;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    padding-top: 0.95em;
    height: 2em;
    width: 5.5em;
    bottom: 100%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    pointer-events: none;
    font-family: 'Oduda-Bold-Demo';
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.1,0.2,1);
    transform: scale3d(0.1,0.2,1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 120%;
    transform-origin: 50% 120%;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.4s;
    transition: opacity 0.4s, transform 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease, cubic-bezier(0.6,0,0.4,1);
    transition-timing-function: ease, cubic-bezier(0.6,0,0.4,1);
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltip-content {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
    transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
}

/* Arrow */

.tooltip-content::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px;
    top: 100%;
    background: #00AEEF;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-60%,0) rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg);
    transform: translate3d(0,-60%,0) rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg);
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Is the tooltip visible, but not positioned correctly, or does the tooltip not appear at all?

Comment: This happens because you listen only to mouseenter, add listeners to mousemove (and if needed add for mouseout to remove tooltip).

Comment: The tooltip is there but not positioned correctly. It looks like the base point for the tooltip is not the current mouse location